# Do you need to filter a final GPS [NOT PSEUDORANGE] data with Kalman Filter again?

Tags: gps

1. I have a projected data in northing, easting, elevation that came from a GPS receiver fitted on a Pipeline Inspection Gauge (PIG). (I do not have the raw data at all)
2. This PIG collected the GPS data by going through an old pipeline which is buried a few meters under the ground at most places. (There are no drawings showing the pipeline original alignment)
3. The northing, easting, elevation data looks fine, i.e. it plots as a nice line without any oscillations or zigzag pattern.
4. I have have been told to correct this data, i.e. to make sure that the alignment we see is the actual alignment of the pipeline underground.
5. I do not have any additional control point or Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) data, i.e. the bends depicted by the GPS data may not be a true bend at all.
6. I have been told that you can use the Kalman filter to filter the northing, easting, elevation data.
7. So, my question WHY? Why do you want to filter the GPS data that has already been filtered inside the receiver (and probably with a kalman filter)?
8. Moreover, I have been arguing that we need additional information to check the accuracy of the data and the northing, easting, and elevation information ALONE cannot be used as a input for further filtering.

Comment: It seems like you do need to filter the data, if only because your supervisor told you to. But it also doesn't seem like they gave you enough information to do it the way they want it done. I suggest asking them to demonstrate exactly how they want this analysis done. You can phrase it along the lines of, "Can you show me exactly which parameters you would use for this calculation, so I can make sure I do it the way you want it." Maybe there's additional data somewhere that they (incorrectly) assume you have access to.

Comment: Thanks @csk. I shall definitely discuss more and see if they are wanting to see additional data. Thanks !